# How to upload image on web from mysql only in jsp

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

Currently I am working on a web site which is totally in html+jsp using eclips. Now my problem  is in uploading a file. I am able to display image from my local machine to my html page,but I want to store that image into mysql database and then display on main web page.

Suppose I have two pages in first page operator select any image from its local machine then it will also display on image view on same page,and when operator click on upload image then image will display on web-site.

As said earlier I am able to display image on operator's page but how to save it in mysql database and then retrieve it on web-site.

It could be possible to do this task in .jsp file only?

Here is my code to display image from local machine,

```
  <div class="file">
<ul class="thumbnails">
<li class="span4">
<a href="#" class="thumbnail">
<div id="imgThumbId"></div>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
<form action="advertise.jsp">
<fieldset>
        <legend>Upload Image</legend>
        <label for="file">Choose photo</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="upload" id="upload" value="Upload photo"  onclick="PreviewRecipeImage();"/>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
    </div>
```

and here is javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">



 function PreviewRecipeImage(){


var file = document.getElementById('file').files[0]; // create img tag for selected recipe image file
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.id = "imgid";
img.classList.add("obj");
img.file = file;
//img.width = 90;
//img.height = 90;
//ClearThumb1Image();

 document.getElementById('imgThumbId').appendChild(img);// append img tag to recipe image tag

var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = (function(aImg) { return function(e) { aImg.src = e.target.result; }; })(img);
reader.readAsDataURL(file);


}
</script>
```

Comment: would it possible to send value from jsp to javascript or html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="file" >
<ul class="thumbnails">
<li class="span4">
<a href="#" class="thumbnail">
<div id="imgThumbId"></div>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
<form action="advertise.jsp" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<fieldset>
        <legend>Upload Image</legend>
        <label for="file">Choose photo</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="upload" id="upload" value="Upload photo"  onclick="PreviewRecipeImage();"/>
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

Use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form.

To handle multipart/form-data, use following servlet code. And also import  [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/)  package in your code.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        List<FileItem> items = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
        for (FileItem item : items) {
            if (item.isFormField()) {
                // Process regular form field (input type="text|radio|checkbox|etc", select, etc).
                String fieldname = item.getFieldName();
                String fieldvalue = item.getString();
                // ... (do your job here)
            } else {
                // Process form file field (input type="file").
                String fieldname = item.getFieldName();
                String filename = FilenameUtils.getName(item.getName());
                InputStream filecontent = item.getInputStream();
                // ... (do your job here)
            }
        }
    } catch (FileUploadException e) {
        throw new ServletException("Cannot parse multipart request.", e);
    }

    // ...
}
```